# Error when sending long SMS message

Tags: sms, gsm

I am doing a long SMS project but I have encountered some problems. I am able to send 2 SMS messages as one long message, but the text that appears doesn't seem to be right. I know there is an error at A0 indicating a 160 word so the SMS has a @ word filling all the empty space. But what I mean is the actually SMS text is corrupted.

The 2 SMS I send:

```
AT+CMGS=28

0041000A9156186651270000A0050003000201E8F71D14969741F9771D

AT+CMGS=23

0041010A9156186651270000A0050003000202E8329BFD06
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is very confusing. Could you please simplify it and explain how you are doing what you are doing and with what tools.

Comment: When sending long messages via the SMPP protocol they are normally sent out as multi-part messages where a User Data Header (UDH) record is prepended to the start of the individual message parts to indicate which part of the message each part is. To let the receiver know that a message is part of a multipart message the User Data Header Indicator (UDHI) bit is set on ESM Class part of the SMS Header. It looks like you're using AT commands via a GSM modem directly but it would be helpful to know what technology you're using to test this on.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the PDU is wrongly encoded. With concatenated SMS's you must include the UDH (so you also need to set in the SMS header octet the flag to say a UDH is included). And of course ensure that the message text starts on a septet boundary.

There are a few tutorials on the web:

http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/

Which explain things in more detail and also in a very understandable way. I suggest you take at look a them and check the way you are encoding your messages.